# Detener hover con un click jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, bootstrap, css3

Estoy trabajando con HTML5, Bootstrap, JQuery y CSS 3, tengo un grid en el cual se comienzan a marcar los `div` segun el color del botón seleccionado, no se comienza a pintar el div hasta que das click de donde quieres comenzar a pintar.
Aquí es donde esta el problema, al dar otro click se debe dejar de efectuar el hover, al parecer lo hace, pero solo es un efecto ya que si paso sobre los `div` que ya se pintaron los comienza a pintar nuevamente de el mismo color de los que no se encuentran marcados. 
La pregunta es:

1. Como detener el hover al dar click donde quieres dejar de efectuar el cambio de color al div?.
2. Que al elegir otro botón de un color distinto, se efectué la misma acción.?

```js
function rgb2hex(rgb) {
  if (/^#[0-9A-F]{6}$/i.test(rgb))
    return rgb;

  rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);

  function hex(x) {
    return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
  }
  return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  let cons = 168;
  let btn_1 = "";
  let price = "";
  let matriz = [];
  let color = false;

  for (var i = 1; i <= cons; i++) {
    $("#calendar_" + i).click(function() {
      if (!color) {
        color = true;
        for (let i = 1; i <= cons; i++) {
          $("#calendar_" + i).hover(function() {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
          }, function() {
            //establece los valores en los divs como atributos
            $(this).css("background-color", btn_1);
            $(this).attr("data-color", btn_1);
            $(this).attr("price", price);

            //Pasa el valor rgb a hexadecimal
            var hex = rgb2hex($(this).attr("data-color"));

            //Asigna valores a las variables con los valores obtenidos de los atributos
            var arr1 = $(this).attr("id");
            var arr2 = hex;
            var arr3 = $(this).attr("price");

            //Concatena los valores en 1 cadena separada por comas
            var rest = arr1.concat(",", arr2, ",", arr3);

            //Genera un array con los valores de la concatenacion
            matriz.push(rest);
          });
        }
      } else {
        color = false;
        for (let i = 1; i <= cons; i++) {
          $("#calendar_" + i).hover(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).css("background-color", "");
          }, function() {
            $(this).css("background-color", "");
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }

  $(document).on('click', 'input[type="button"]', function() {
    let id = this.id;
    btn_1 = $("#" + id).css("background-color");
    price = $("#" + id).attr("price");
  });
});
```

```css
.grid-container-dias {
  display: grid;
  height: auto;
  align-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 5px;
}

.grid-container-dias>div {
  background-color: transparent;
  ;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 0;
  font-size: 11px;
  width: 143px;
  height: 10px;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  height: auto;
  align-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 8px;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 5px;
}

.grid-container>div {
  background-color: #d5d5d5;
  ;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-size: 11px;
  width: 143px;
  height: 10px;
}

.text-horas-superior {
  position: relative;
  top: -22px;
  left: 11px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.text-horas-inferior {
  position: relative;
  top: -11px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.text-horas-resto {
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
  left: 11px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.btn-pago-hora-extra-1 {
  background-color: #3d6cb2;
}

.btn-pago-hora-extra-2 {
  background-color: #21aad6;
}

.btn-pago-hora-extra-3 {
  background-color: #3bbdb8;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-md-9">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="grid-container-dias">
          <div style="background-color: transparent; width: 43px; position: relative;"></div>
          <div class="text-calendario tamanio-fuente-12">DOMINGO</div>
          <div class="text-calendario tamanio-fuente-12">LUNES</div>
          <div class="text-calendario tamanio-fuente-12">MARTES</div>
          <div class="text-calendario tamanio-fuente-12">MIERCOLES</div>
          <div class="text-calendario tamanio-fuente-12">JUEVES</div>
          <div class="text-calendario tamanio-fuente-12">VIERNES</div>
          <div class="text-calendario tamanio-fuente-12">SABADO</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="grid" class="grid-container">
          <div style="background-color: transparent; width: 43px; position: relative;">
            <span class="text-horas-superior">00:00</span><br/>
            <span class="text-horas-inferior">01:00</span>
          </div>
          <div id="calendar_1"></div>
          <div id="calendar_2"></div>
          <div id="calendar_3"></div>
          <div id="calendar_4"></div>
          <div id="calendar_5"></div>
          <div id="calendar_6"></div>
          <div id="calendar_7"></div>
          <div style="background-color: transparent; width: 43px; position: relative;"><span class="text-horas-resto">02:00</span></div>
          <div id="calendar_8"></div>
          <div id="calendar_9"></div>
          <div id="calendar_10"></div>
          <div id="calendar_11"></div>
          <div id="calendar_12"></div>
          <div id="calendar_13"></div>
          <div id="calendar_14"></div>
          <div style="background-color: transparent; width: 43px; position: relative;"><span class="text-horas-resto">03:00</span></div>
          <div id="calendar_15"></div>
          <div id="calendar_16"></div>
          <div id="calendar_17"></div>
          <div id="calendar_18"></div>
          <div id="calendar_19"></div>
          <div id="calendar_20"></div>
          <div id="calendar_21"></div>
          <div style="background-color: transparent; width: 43px; position: relative;"><span class="text-horas-resto">04:00</span></div>
          <div id="calendar_22"></div>
          <div id="calendar_23"></div>
          <div id="calendar_24"></div>
          <div id="calendar_25"></div>
          <div id="calendar_26"></div>
          <div id="calendar_27"></div>
          <div id="calendar_28"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-12">
    <input id="btn_pago_horas_extra_1" name="btn_pago_horas_extra_1" type="button" class=" btn-pago-hora-extra-1" price="85" value="$ 85 por hora" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-12">
    <input id="btn_pago_horas_extra_2" name="btn_pago_horas_extra_2" type="button" class=" btn-pago-hora-extra-2" price="110" value="$ 110 por hora" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-12">
    <input id="btn_pago_horas_extra_3" name="btn_pago_horas_extra_3" type="button" class=" btn-pago-hora-extra-3" price="150" value="$ 150 por hora" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Porque no usas una bandera para saber si se dio click o esta en hover y deja la función del click definida antes de la de hover con un e.preventDefault() o e.stopPropagation(). Tambien puedes ver los eventos mouseover, mouseout, etc https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_mouseover.asp

Answer (score 0):

La parte del "hover" yo lo haría con css con la propiedad `:hover` y luego al hacer clic en el objeto agregaría una clase ya que entre mas específico es el selector css mas prioridad tendrá, de esta forma agregué estas clases

```
.grid-container div:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.grid-container div.clicked {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

el segundo selector css tiene un nivel mas de exactitud por lo que tendrá mas prioridad que el hover

```js
function rgb2hex(rgb) {
  if (/^#[0-9A-F]{6}$/i.test(rgb))
    return rgb;

  rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);

  function hex(x) {
    return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
  }
  return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  let cons = 168;
  let btn_1 = "";
  let price = "";
  let matriz = [];
  let color = false;

  // funcion para agregar clase "clicked" a los cuadrados grises
  $(document).on('click', '#grid div', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
  })

  $(document).on('click', 'input[type="button"]', function() {
    let id = this.id;
    btn_1 = $("#" + id).css("background-color");
    price = $("#" + id).attr("price");
  });
});
```

```css
.grid-container-dias {
  display: grid;
  height: auto;
  align-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 5px;
}

.grid-container-dias>div {
  background-color: transparent;
  ;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 0;
  font-size: 11px;
  width: 143px;
  height: 10px;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  height: auto;
  align-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 8px;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 5px;
}

.grid-container>div {
  background-color: #d5d5d5;
  ;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-size: 11px;
  width: 143px;
  height: 10px;
}

.text-horas-superior {
  position: relative;
  top: -22px;
  left: 11px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.text-horas-inferior {
  position: relative;
  top: -11px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.text-horas-resto {
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
  left: 11px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.btn-pago-hora-extra-1 {
  background-color: #3d6cb2;
}

.btn-pago-hora-extra-2 {
  background-color: #21aad6;
}

.btn-pago-hora-extra-3 {
  background-color: #3bbdb8;
}



.grid-container div:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.grid-container div.clicked {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-md-9">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="grid-container-dias">
          <div style="background-color: transparent; width: 43px; position: relative;"></div>
          <div class="text-calendario tamanio-fuente-12">DOMINGO</div>
          <div class="text-calendario tamanio-fuente-12">LUNES</div>
          <div class="text-calendario tamanio-fuente-12">MARTES</div>
          <div class="text-calendario tamanio-fuente-12">MIERCOLES</div>
          <div class="text-calendario tamanio-fuente-12">JUEVES</div>
          <div class="text-calendario tamanio-fuente-12">VIERNES</div>
          <div class="text-calendario tamanio-fuente-12">SABADO</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="grid" class="grid-container">
          <div style="background-color: transparent; width: 43px; position: relative;">
            <span class="text-horas-superior">00:00</span><br/>
            <span class="text-horas-inferior">01:00</span>
          </div>
          <div id="calendar_1"></div>
          <div id="calendar_2"></div>
          <div id="calendar_3"></div>
          <div id="calendar_4"></div>
          <div id="calendar_5"></div>
          <div id="calendar_6"></div>
          <div id="calendar_7"></div>
          <div style="background-color: transparent; width: 43px; position: relative;"><span class="text-horas-resto">02:00</span></div>
          <div id="calendar_8"></div>
          <div id="calendar_9"></div>
          <div id="calendar_10"></div>
          <div id="calendar_11"></div>
          <div id="calendar_12"></div>
          <div id="calendar_13"></div>
          <div id="calendar_14"></div>
          <div style="background-color: transparent; width: 43px; position: relative;"><span class="text-horas-resto">03:00</span></div>
          <div id="calendar_15"></div>
          <div id="calendar_16"></div>
          <div id="calendar_17"></div>
          <div id="calendar_18"></div>
          <div id="calendar_19"></div>
          <div id="calendar_20"></div>
          <div id="calendar_21"></div>
          <div style="background-color: transparent; width: 43px; position: relative;"><span class="text-horas-resto">04:00</span></div>
          <div id="calendar_22"></div>
          <div id="calendar_23"></div>
          <div id="calendar_24"></div>
          <div id="calendar_25"></div>
          <div id="calendar_26"></div>
          <div id="calendar_27"></div>
          <div id="calendar_28"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-12">
    <input id="btn_pago_horas_extra_1" name="btn_pago_horas_extra_1" type="button" class=" btn-pago-hora-extra-1" price="85" value="$ 85 por hora" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-12">
    <input id="btn_pago_horas_extra_2" name="btn_pago_horas_extra_2" type="button" class=" btn-pago-hora-extra-2" price="110" value="$ 110 por hora" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-12">
    <input id="btn_pago_horas_extra_3" name="btn_pago_horas_extra_3" type="button" class=" btn-pago-hora-extra-3" price="150" value="$ 150 por hora" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolví, dejo lo que me funciono de la manera que lo requiero por si alguien le sirve.
Gracias a todos por sus respuestas.

```js
function rgb2hex(rgb) {
  if (/^#[0-9A-F]{6}$/i.test(rgb))
    return rgb;

  rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);

  function hex(x) {
    return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
  }
  return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  let cons = 168;
  let btn_1 = "";
  let price = "";
  let matriz = [];
  let color = false;

  for (var i = 1; i <= cons; i++) {
    $("#calendar_" + i).click(function() {
      if (!color) {
        color = true;
        for (let i = 1; i <= cons; i++) {
          $("#calendar_" + i).hover(function() {
            $(this).css('background-color', btn_1);
          }, function() {
            //establece los valores en los divs como atributos
            $(this).css("background-color", btn_1);
            $(this).attr("data-color", btn_1);
            $(this).attr("price", price);

            //Pasa el valor rgb a hexadecimal
            var hex = rgb2hex($(this).attr("data-color"));

            //Asigna valores a las variables con los valores obtenidos de los atributos
            var arr1 = $(this).attr("id");
            var arr2 = hex;
            var arr3 = $(this).attr("price");

            //Concatena los valores en 1 cadena separada por comas
            var rest = arr1.concat(",", arr2, ",", arr3);

            //Genera un array con los valores de la concatenacion
            matriz.push(rest);
          });
        }
      } else {
        color = false;
        for (let i = 1; i <= cons; i++) {
          $("#calendar_" + i).unbind("mouseenter mouseleave");
        }
      }
    });
  }

  $(document).on('click', 'input[type="button"]', function() {
    let id = this.id;
    btn_1 = $("#" + id).css("background-color");
    price = $("#" + id).attr("price");
  });
});
```

```css
.grid-container-dias {
  display: grid;
  height: auto;
  align-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 5px;
}

.grid-container-dias>div {
  background-color: transparent;
  ;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 0;
  font-size: 11px;
  width: 143px;
  height: 10px;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  height: auto;
  align-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 8px;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 5px;
}

.grid-container>div {
  background-color: #d5d5d5;
  ;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-size: 11px;
  width: 143px;
  height: 10px;
}

.text-horas-superior {
  position: relative;
  top: -22px;
  left: 11px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.text-horas-inferior {
  position: relative;
  top: -11px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.text-horas-resto {
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
  left: 11px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.btn-pago-hora-extra-1 {
  background-color: #3d6cb2;
}

.btn-pago-hora-extra-2 {
  background-color: #21aad6;
}

.btn-pago-hora-extra-3 {
  background-color: #3bbdb8;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-md-9">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="grid-container-dias">
          <div style="background-color: transparent; width: 43px; position: relative;"></div>
          <div class="text-calendario tamanio-fuente-12">DOMINGO</div>
          <div class="text-calendario tamanio-fuente-12">LUNES</div>
          <div class="text-calendario tamanio-fuente-12">MARTES</div>
          <div class="text-calendario tamanio-fuente-12">MIERCOLES</div>
          <div class="text-calendario tamanio-fuente-12">JUEVES</div>
          <div class="text-calendario tamanio-fuente-12">VIERNES</div>
          <div class="text-calendario tamanio-fuente-12">SABADO</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="grid" class="grid-container">
          <div style="background-color: transparent; width: 43px; position: relative;">
            <span class="text-horas-superior">00:00</span><br/>
            <span class="text-horas-inferior">01:00</span>
          </div>
          <div id="calendar_1"></div>
          <div id="calendar_2"></div>
          <div id="calendar_3"></div>
          <div id="calendar_4"></div>
          <div id="calendar_5"></div>
          <div id="calendar_6"></div>
          <div id="calendar_7"></div>
          <div style="background-color: transparent; width: 43px; position: relative;"><span class="text-horas-resto">02:00</span></div>
          <div id="calendar_8"></div>
          <div id="calendar_9"></div>
          <div id="calendar_10"></div>
          <div id="calendar_11"></div>
          <div id="calendar_12"></div>
          <div id="calendar_13"></div>
          <div id="calendar_14"></div>
          <div style="background-color: transparent; width: 43px; position: relative;"><span class="text-horas-resto">03:00</span></div>
          <div id="calendar_15"></div>
          <div id="calendar_16"></div>
          <div id="calendar_17"></div>
          <div id="calendar_18"></div>
          <div id="calendar_19"></div>
          <div id="calendar_20"></div>
          <div id="calendar_21"></div>
          <div style="background-color: transparent; width: 43px; position: relative;"><span class="text-horas-resto">04:00</span></div>
          <div id="calendar_22"></div>
          <div id="calendar_23"></div>
          <div id="calendar_24"></div>
          <div id="calendar_25"></div>
          <div id="calendar_26"></div>
          <div id="calendar_27"></div>
          <div id="calendar_28"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-12">
    <input id="btn_pago_horas_extra_1" name="btn_pago_horas_extra_1" type="button" class=" btn-pago-hora-extra-1" price="85" value="$ 85 por hora" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-12">
    <input id="btn_pago_horas_extra_2" name="btn_pago_horas_extra_2" type="button" class=" btn-pago-hora-extra-2" price="110" value="$ 110 por hora" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-12">
    <input id="btn_pago_horas_extra_3" name="btn_pago_horas_extra_3" type="button" class=" btn-pago-hora-extra-3" price="150" value="$ 150 por hora" />
  </div>
</div>
```

en el else de la condición hubo que cambiar el evento `hover()` por `unbind()` quedando de la siguiente manera `$("#calendar_" + i).unbind("mouseenter mouseleave");` 
con esto se resolvió y funciona de la manera esperada, al dar click por segunda vez se detiene el hover y no continua hasta que se vuelva a dar click en otra sección del grid ya sea eligiendo otro color o con el mismo ya elegido.